# How can I make two controller(parameter is different) in swagger2.0?

Tags: rest, api, swagger

I wanna create flexible api method like following

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> addItem(@RequestBody ItemRequest itemRequest){

}
public ResponseEntity<Void> addItems(@RequestBody List<ItemRequest> itemRequests){

}
```

Client can transfer two type json like following

```
{
  "name" : "name"
  "age" : 27
}



[
  {
    "name" : "name1"
    "age" : 27
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2"
    "age" : 27
  }
]
```

Actually It's possible to transfer list that have only one element.
But.. I wanna create flexible api T.T

And then I tried to describe two `post` api, but it can't.

```
items:
  post:
    operationId: addItem
    parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        schema: 
          $ref: '#/ItemSaveRequest'

  post:
    operationId: addItems
    parameters:
      - in: body
        name: body
        schema: 
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/ItemSaveRequest'
```

But you know, it's impossible.
Is there any way to do this?
Thanks to read this.

Comment: I don't see gaining any flexibility with providing 2 endpoints that accept the same request, but one accepts single request type and the other a list of the same request type. Just go with List<ItemRequest> and move on.

Comment: Yes... after submit this, I thought like you.